# DataBinding in List

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to bind data within a ArrayList to a list, but here only the last element shows up on the list(99), not the entire contents of the arraylist.

```
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var xmlData:XML = XML(event.target.data);
            trace(xmlData);
             var i:int = 0;
            for (i;i<100;i++)
            {
                var arr:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
                arr.addItem(i);
                trace(arr);
            } 
            list.dataProvider = arr;
        }
```

I am not able to figure out what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an ArrayList with one item a 100 times. Replace with this and you should be fine:

```
var arr:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
for (var i:int = 0; i<100; i++) {
    arr.addItem(i);
}
```

Or better yet, just wrap your XML in an XMLListCollection instead of copying the nodes one by one (assuming it is the actual content of the XML data you want instead of the indices):

```
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var xmlData:XML = XML(event.target.data);
    list.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(xmlData.children());
}
```

(Note that this is not DataBinding: it is just setting the `dataProvider` property)

Answer (score 0):

check this code this will help you,

you can navigate through all data on the basis of rowcount of list....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"  minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]private var _index:int = 0;
            private var _coll:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{name:'ashish',age:'28'},{name:'abhi',age:'29'},{name:'kunal',age:'27'},
                {name:'ashish1',age:'28'},{name:'abhi1',age:'29'},{name:'kunal1',age:'27'},
                {name:'ashish2',age:'28'},{name:'abhi2',age:'29'},{name:'kunal2',age:'27'},
                {name:'ashish3',age:'28'},{name:'abhi3',age:'29'},{name:'kunal3',age:'27'}]);

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if((_index-li.rowCount>=0))
                    _index =  _index - li.rowCount;
            }


            protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if((_index+li.rowCount<_coll.length))
                    _index =  _index + li.rowCount;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:List id="li" dataProvider="{_coll.source.slice(_index,(_index+li.rowCount))}" labelField="name" rowCount="3" width="100"/> 

    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Button label="&lt;-" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <mx:Button label="->" click="button2_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```